# Mac App not being signed correctly

Tags: cocoa, code-signing, mac-app-store, receipt

I know there are many similar questions on StackOverflow, but I think I've read them all and none quite apply.

I have a Cocoa app that I am trying to sign for distribution on the Mac App Store. I have created my distribution profile and I believe it's all hooked up correctly in XCode. When I build the app, XCode prompts me about signing and the build finishes with no errors. When I look at the build messages, I see a happy green check mark from Code Sign.

Further, I'm using Receigen for the receipt validation, and when I use it to inspect my built app, it shows that the app is indeed signed and that the signature is valid.

*However*...when I copy the app to a different machine (running Snow Leopard, if that makes a difference) and launch the app there, I see that after the app quits with code 173 for receipt validation, Console shows that storeagent logs the message "Unsigned app." Similarly, when I inspect the app with Receigen, it shows that the app is signed but not valid. Why could this be?

Tangentially, in case it helps spur some ideas, the context of this is that I'm trying to get receipt validation working, and on my main dev box (the one in which the app shows as being signed correctly), when I exit with 173, I am prompted with the iTunes credential challenge, although the receipt is never retrieved from the store. On the other machine, I never even receive the credential challenge (I presume and hope this is all because of the same issue).

I'm really at wits' end here. Thank you, fine people of StackOverflow, for any ideas you might have.

Comment: Update: I finally got things working, but unfortunately, I was never able to determine exactly what the issue was. However, it appears something was configured incorrectly or corrupted somewhere in my project file. I created a new project, copied all my source code and resources into it, and rebuilt, and the problem magically went away. My advice if you're seeing this would be to create a toy app that uses the same bundle ID and if you can get it working, just proceed with that one as I did.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, the answer is in a comment from @Brian Rak:

> Update: I finally got things working, but unfortunately, I was never
>   able to determine exactly what the issue was. However, it appears
>   something was configured incorrectly or corrupted somewhere in my
>   project file. I created a new project, copied all my source code and
>   resources into it, and rebuilt, and the problem magically went away.
>   My advice if you're seeing this would be to create a toy app that uses
>   the same bundle ID and if you can get it working, just proceed with
>   that one as I did.